# Why new created ServiceAccount has 0 secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, k8s-serviceaccount

I have Kubernetes version 1.24.3, and I created a new service account named "deployer", but when I checked it, it shows it doesn't have any secrets.

This is how I created the service account:

```
kubectl apply -f - << EOF
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deployer
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: deployer-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs: ["list", "get", "describe", "apply", "delete", "patch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: deployer-crb
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: deployer-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: deployer
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: token-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: deployer
EOF
```

When I checked it, it shows that it doesn't have secrets:

```
cyber@manager1:~$ kubectl get sa deployer
NAME       SECRETS   AGE
deployer   0         4m32s

cyber@manager1:~$ kubectl get sa deployer -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"deployer","namespace":"default"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-10-13T08:36:54Z"
  name: deployer
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2129964"
  uid: cd2bf19f-92b2-4830-8b5a-879914a18af5
```

And this is the secret that should be associated to the above service account:

```
cyber@manager1:~$ kubectl get secrets token-secret -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: <REDACTED>
  namespace: ZGVmYXVsdA==
  token: <REDACTED>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/service-account.name":"deployer"},"name":"token-secret","namespace":"default"},"type":"kubernetes.io/service-account-token"}
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: deployer
    kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: cd2bf19f-92b2-4830-8b5a-879914a18af5
  creationTimestamp: "2022-10-13T08:36:54Z"
  name: token-secret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2129968"
  uid: d960c933-5e7b-4750-865d-e843f52f1b48
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

What can be the reason?

**Update:**
The answer help, but for the protocol, it doesn't matter, the token works even it shows 0 secrets:

```
kubectl get pods --token `cat ./token` -s https://192.168.49.2:8443 --certificate-authority /home/cyber/.minikube/ca.crt --all-namespaces
```

**Other Details:**
I am working on Kubernetes version 1.24:

```
cyber@manager1:~$ kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.0", GitCommit:"a866cbe2e5bbaa01cfd5e969aa3e033f3282a8a2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-23T17:44:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.19", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.3", GitCommit:"aef86a93758dc3cb2c658dd9657ab4ad4afc21cb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-07-13T14:23:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

You can delete it by running:

```
kubectl delete clusterroles deployer-role
kubectl delete clusterrolebindings deployer-crb 
kubectl delete sa deployer  
kubectl delete secrets token-secret
```

Reference to Kubernetes 1.24 changes:

- [Change log 1.24](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md#no-really-you-must-read-this-before-you-upgrade)
- [Creating secret through the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the change log, the auto-generation of tokens is no longer available for every service account.

> The LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration feature gate is beta, and enabled by default. **When enabled, Secret API objects containing service account tokens are no longer auto-generated for every ServiceAccount**. Use the TokenRequest API to acquire service account tokens, or if a non-expiring token is required, create a Secret API object for the token controller to populate with a service account token by following this guide.

[token-request-v1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/authentication-resources/token-request-v1/)

[stops auto-generation of legacy tokens because they are less secure](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/108309)

[work-around](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/8320#issuecomment-1271354662)

or you can use

```
kubectl create token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
kubectl create token deployer
```

[Request a service account token.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-token-em-)

Comment: The `kubectl create token deployer` just generates a token, but it doesn't change the object. The secret already has a token so it doesn't solve it.

Comment: so `token-secret` is using the SA to create token (so this token can perform action that SA can), i do not think it will populate the service account

Comment: or you can try `kubectl patch sa deployer -p '{"secrets": [{"name": "token-secret"}]}'`

Comment: Thanks, it now shows at least one. But I checked it, it doesn't matter, it also works when the secrets shows 0:  `kubectl get pods --token `cat ./token` -s https://192.168.49.2:8443 --certificate-authority /home/cyber/.minikube/ca.crt --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 1):

Should the roleRef not reference the developer Role which has the name deployer role. Inwould try to replace

```
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: sdr
```

with

```
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: deplyer-role
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a bug in my code, I changed it but it still has 0 secrets